# How to enable .htaccess in httpd.conf on XP?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, windows-xp, httpd.conf

I would like to use mod_rewrite() on my apache setup on a windows machine. As you probably know, Windows doesn't use Unix-style hidden filenames like ".htaccess."

So should I change `AccessFileName .htaccess` to `AccessFileName xyz.htaccess` ?

or there is something else I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only Windows Explorer that won't let you create dot-filenames.  Create the file with any name you like, then use a Command Prompt to rename it:

```
ren pog.htaccess .htaccess
```

You can then edit it using Notepad or whatever to your heart's content, and you'll still be using the same filename as everyone else.

Windows Explorer will happily let you move the file around and so on even with a dot-filename - it's just naming or renaming such files that fails.

Answer (score 0):

Open up your httpd.conf. Change this line in  to the following:

```
AccessFileName ht.acl .htaccess
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache on Windows should use it, it just won't be hidden.